# What does "beginning of birth pangs" mean in the context of Mathew 24:4-8?

Tags: matthew, prophecy, olivet-discourse

At the end of his gospel on the tail end of a warning passage, Mathew uses the expression "beginning of birth pangs". What does he mean?

> And Jesus answered and said to them, “See to it that no one misleads
>   you.  For many will come in My name, saying, ‘I am the Christ,’ and
>   will mislead many.  You will be hearing of wars and rumors of wars.
>   See that you are not frightened, for those things must take place, but
>   that is not yet the end.  For nation will rise against nation, and
>   kingdom against kingdom, and in various places there will be famines
>   and earthquakes. ***But all these things are merely the beginning of
>   birth pangs.***
>   — Mathew 24:4-8 (emphasis added)

Answer (score 6):

In this context, the Greek ὠδῖνες refer to the birth pangs a woman experiences while in labor. Basically, the Jews referred to these by the phrase חבלי דמשיח <sup>1</sup> or חבלו של משיח,<sup>2</sup> literally "the birth pangs of the Messiah." They are not birth pangs that the Messiah himself experiences (a subjective genitive, if you will), but birth pangs that Israel (personified as a woman) experiences which culminate in the "birth" (i.e., coming into the world) of the Messiah (an objective genitive, if you will).

In other words, Israel will experience great distress and tribulation (represented as birth pangs, ὠδῖνες, or חבלים) before the coming of the Messiah into the world. The  notion of of these birth pangs preceding the Messianic advent originated from the Tanakh.<sup>3</sup>

---

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Babylonian Talmud, Ktubot 111a | [Hebrew](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/l/l3213.htm) | [English](http://www.halakhah.com/pdf/nashim/Kethuboth.pdf) |

<sup>2</sup> Babylonian Talmud, Sanhedrin 98b | [Hebrew](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/l/l4411.htm) | [English](http://www.halakhah.com/pdf/nezikin/Sanhedrin.pdf) |

<sup>3</sup> cp. [Isa 13:8](http://www.blbclassic.org/Bible.cfm?b=Isa&c=13&v=8&t=KJV#conc/8), [26:17](http://www.blbclassic.org/Bible.cfm?b=Isa&c=26&v=17&t=KJV#conc/17), [66:7-8](http://www.blbclassic.org/Bible.cfm?b=Isa&c=66&v=1&t=KJV#conc/8); [Jer. 30:5-7](http://www.blbclassic.org/Bible.cfm?b=Jer&c=30&v=1&t=KJV#conc/5)

Answer (score 2):

#### *What does "beginning of birth pangs" mean in the context of Mathew 24:4-8?*

Answer: **We must begin at verse 3 to correctly interpret what follows**:

> **Matthew 24:3**: "As [Christ] was sitting on the Mount of Olives, the disciples came to Him privately, saying, 'Tell us, [1]when will these things happen, and [2]what will be the sign of Your coming, and [3]of the end of the age?'”

It is vital to observe that **three distinct questions are raised** (as highlighted in the above bracketed numbers):
1. When will these things happen?
2. What will be the sign of Your coming?
3. [What will be the sign] of the end of the age [world]?

It seems unlikely, at this point in Jesus' ministry, that the disciples could fathom the totality of His message. That understanding would follow later when they reflected back on His words, guided by the Holy Spirit. Here, they seemed to have considered the three events to be simultaneous, but *this is not the case*.

Christ answered their questions, providing crucial details of the sign of his coming (last, vss. 36-41) while first outlining the striking features of the destruction of Jerusalem (A.D. 70), which typified His second coming. He set forth specifics applicable to both events. As [Coffman](https://www.studylight.org/commentaries/eng/bcc/matthew-24.html) observes:

> Practically all of the difficulties in understanding this astounding chapter will disappear when it is remembered that in a single prophecy Christ foretold the destruction of Jerusalem and the final judgment and destruction of the whole world, making the first a type of the latter, and choosing a number of details that apply to both. Just as the rainbow is not one bow but actually two, a primary and a secondary, so many of the prophecies of the word of God have a primary and a secondary fulfillment. "Rachel weeping for her children" (Jeremiah 31:15) and "Out of Egypt have I called my son" (Hosea 11:1) are two examples (see on Matthew 2:13,18). Dummelow stated that "Our Lord referred in it not to one event but to two, and the first was typical of the second."<sup>1</sup>
>
> H. Leo Boles also noted<sup>2</sup> such a characteristic of divine prophecy, saying:
>
> > Often prophetic language has a double significance. Jehovah told Adam that he would die in the day that he ate the forbidden fruit (Genesis 2:17); yet Adam lived 930 years. There was a primary fulfillment of this when Adam was separated from the garden of Eden, and a secondary fulfillment of it in his death (Romans 5:12). Isaiah foretold the birth of a son by a virgin, yet added a prophecy which confined it to his own generation (Isaiah 7:14-17). The prophet combined type and anti-type in the same words.

<sup>1</sup> J. R. Dummelow, op. cit., p. 702.
<sup>2</sup> H. Leo Boles, Commentary on Matthew (Nashville: The Gospel Advocate Company, 1936), p. 472.

We might also note the next verse, one of those in question, by itself (followed by Coffman's remarks):

> **Matthew 24:4**: "And Jesus answered and said to them, 'See to it that no one misleads you.'
> [Coffman:] This admonition was especially appropriate in view of the amazing answer Christ was about to give to a [multi-part] question, the complexity of which would not be revealed to them except through the unfolding of future events.

Continuing with the next two verses:

> **Matthew 24:5-6**: "For many will come in My name [false Christs], saying, 'I am the Christ,’ and will mislead many. <sup>6</sup>You will be hearing of wars and rumors of wars. See that you are not frightened, for those things must take place, but that is not yet the end."

The "things" to which Jesus is referring are basically the usual conflicts and misfortunes which befall nearly everyone of all ages. The claims of false teachers has little to do with the impending events prophesied from verse 15 onward. Here is where we begin to see the significance of the discourse:

> **Matthew 24:7-8**: "For nation will rise against nation, and kingdom against kingdom, and in various places there will be famines and earthquakes. <sup>8</sup>But all these things are merely the beginning of birth pangs."

Such catastrophes as famines, wars, earthquakes could be viewed as the "beginning of birth pangs" because, as all of this distress increased, so too did the "pangs" (or travails). They all foreshadowed the far greater destruction and human toll of the Roman siege against Jerusalem:

> **Matthew 24:15-18+**: "Therefore when you see the ABOMINATION OF DESOLATION [Rome] which was spoken of through Daniel the prophet, standing in the holy place (let the reader understand), <sup>16</sup>*then those who are in Judea must flee to the mountains* [due to the imminent siege]. <sup>17</sup>Whoever is on the housetop *must not go down to get the things out that are in his house*. <sup>18</sup>*Whoever is in the field must not turn back to get his cloak*..." (emphasis added).

**The "beginning of birth pangs" is applied to the escalating tribulation of the land prior to the Roman invasion of Israel beginning in verse 15**.

Answer (score 0):

Following birth pains comes forth an infant who grows to be a toddler, a toddler that matures into a verbally competent child, and thence towards adolescence, young adulthood and maturity. In envisioning the broken down buildings of the temple complex just before his comments on the pains of childbirth, Jesus sees the death of animal sacrificial worship that's near two millennia old, and had long since been anchored in the temple. Behold, a new thing is about to be born, the body of the once sacrificed for-all risen one, the messiah, is alive on earth today as the Christian church. It, the church, must need go through the same stages of growth and development as a human child. It's been long strange trip thus far, has it not? We, the church, are that person/child and need to understand where we are in our developmental stage. In wealthy, educated parts of the world it seems we have lost ground - maybe we got into early adulthood 2000 years after our "birth" but more recently we have now seemingly relapsed and are continuing that relapse into an even younger self=absorbed adolescence. A new Great Awakening is my prayer for the "west" especially. We who converted much of the world through Spirit-led missionary initiatives are finding the missionary energy flow coming back to us from the southern hemisphere. May we respond and not have to go through a great (parenthesis) as Paul described for so many of the Jews of his day who did not respond to the gospel call as he writes in Romans 11.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).